# Hands on TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to deep learning. I want to test my data on TesonFlow. I have installed TensorFlow through anaconda. Please guide me how to use it for testing my data. I have both windows and linux os. Kindly share some handson for my problem.

Comment: Presumably you've tried looking at the various online tutorials on Tensorflow ? You question is too broad for SO see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple feed forward network using Keras ,a high level API build on top of Tensorflow. 
Learn more from [here](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/introduction-to-deep-learning-with-keras-c7c3d14e1527).